# Analysis Services Cube Name

Tags: sql-server, ssas, alias, cube

I have a multidimensional cube in SSAS 2012 (upgrading to newer SQL version soon), and now need to rename the cube.  Unfortunately by doing so, all other reports and systems which read from this cube will break and need to be fixed to reflect the new cube name.  Is there a way (or workaround) to somehow define an alias for the cube name so that the old reports can still refer to the cube using the old name?

Comment: why do you need to rename the cube?

Comment: It's part of a larger cleanup exercise that's going on

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this. Enterprise edition has translations, but this only works AFAIK on objects within a cube.